# Burial of an infalliable

Tags: source-identification, sharia, shiism, infallability

It is said that only an [infallible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fourteen_Infallibles) can bury another infallible, like [Ali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali)(as) did [Prophet Mohammad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad)(saww)<sub>([Death and Burial](http://www.al-islam.org/life-muhammad-prophet-sayyid-saeed-akhtar-rizvi/death-and-burial) )</sub> and [Fatima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatimah)(as)<sub>([Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatimah#Death))</sub>.

What's the source of this law?  And why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

There are different hadiths about this law. For example:

[Imam Sadiq a.s. said:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27far_al-Sadiq)

> إنّ الامام لایغسله الا الامام
>
> The Imam is not Qusled unless with Imam.
>
> Reference: Usul Kafi, vol 1, page 384

Qusl means religious washing before burial. Also Prophet Muhammad SAWW was both Imam and messenger at the same time.

Also there are 7 hadith in the Hadith collection book Bihar ul Anwar, vol 27, page 288 says this.

This law happened true about all of the fourteen infallibles in past (only Imam Mahdi a.s. is not dead still and he will be included to this law also. Imam Hussain a.s. will become alive again (رجعت) and will do the Qusl of Imam Mahdi a.s.)

**Reference:**

[http://www.porsemanequran.com](http://www.porsemanequran.com/node/23003)

Comment: What's the reason behind this law?

Comment: @hus787 perhaps to people can know real and fake Imam. Imam has a lot of money from Khoms and Zikat and they are transferred to the next Imam. so many greedy people claim to be Imam. but let me do a research and improve the answer if found any result InshaAllah.

Comment: One more thing. Fatima(as) was an infallible but not an Imam. How does Imam Sadiq(as) saying apply in her burial's case?

Comment: @hus787 she was not an Imam because Imam should be man. but she was at the rank of Imam and was among Ahl ul Bayt and was one of the [five members of Kisa](http://www.duas.org/hadis-e-kisa.htm). Maryam a.s. was highest rank woman at her time but Fatima a.s. is the highest rank woman of all times. http://tanzil.net/#3:42

Comment: @BleedingFingers the only reason behind this law I could find from scholars is this verse:http://tanzil.net/#56:79

Comment: That verse seems to be referring to the Quran, AFAIK.

Comment: @BleedingFingers based on hadith of "two weighty things" Quran and Ahl al Bayt are equivalent of  each other. http://www.al-islam.org/shiah-are-real-ahlul-sunnah-muhammad-al-tijani-al-samawi/is-it-book-allah-and-my-progeny-or Quran has different levels of meaning. both are correct.